Display one table row as child of other Table row in Angular



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4



| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
|  Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
I have one for loop in which I am repeating tr but for one row there is child component. No expandable table is there.
I have one table in Angular, table is simple table but I have one row which has child data .and I have to display this child row inside patent but no expandable concept. It's always display. No toggle button is there. I am using angular and for loop running for tr display.

Can you please share your code?

Is your question how to create a row that you can hide?
